# Kendo Grid: Clearing filter without calling server side read of data

Tags: kendo-ui, filtering, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with server side paging. On the same page, I also have a clear button which should clear the data of the grid and replace it with blank rows. Is it possible to clear the filters of that grid, without calling the server side read? Currently when I do this, `$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({})`, it will call the server side function and load the data. Anyone can point me to the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Just making sure, do you want to clear the dataSource filter or clear the grid datasource itself?

Comment: Clear the datasource filter. After that I am adding blank data using JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite serverFiltering set to false by default, it seems that `filter()` automatically calls transport read every single time.

However, you can try this:

```
dataSource._filter = null;
```

This will cancel any filters applied to the dataSource without calling transport read. **But**, you have to be cautious with this approach as it isn't an "official" configuration documented by Telerik. The property `_filter` is internal, so to speak.

You can verify this works by console logging the `requestEnd` event and seeing that this doesn't make a request.

Comment: I was kinda hoping there was another solution. But I guess for now this is the only way. Hope they can give us that functionality officially on the next releases.